# Confused from x86 memory Layout of kernel loader

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, bootloader

I am new to Linux kernel stuff and is reading about memory layout of Kernel loader but confused with below given diagram

```
0A0000  +------------------------+
        |  Reserved for BIOS     |  Do not use.  Reserved for BIOS EBDA.
09A000  +------------------------+
        |  Command line          |
        |  Stack/heap            |  For use by the kernel real-mode code.
098000  +------------------------+  
        |  Kernel setup          |  The kernel real-mode code.
090200  +------------------------+
        |  Kernel boot sector    |  The kernel legacy boot sector.
090000  +------------------------+
        |  Protected-mode kernel |  The bulk of the kernel image.
010000  +------------------------+
        |  Boot loader           |  <- Boot sector entry point 0000:7C00
001000  +------------------------+
        |  Reserved for MBR/BIOS |
000800  +------------------------+
        |  Typically used by MBR |
000600  +------------------------+ 
        |  BIOS use only         |
```

Now statement explaining  this diagram is bit confusing for me.

When using bzImage, the protected-mode kernel was relocated to 0x100000 ("high memory"), and the kernel real-mode block (boot sector,setup, and stack/heap) was made relocatable to any address between 0x10000 and end of low memory.

Now first thing where is 0x100000 address is in above diagram ??

Second thing is when its says kernel real-mode block was made relocatable to "any address between 0x10000 and end of low memory"  means it was relocatable to address between 0x10000 to 000600?

Intially kernle mode block is placed between 0x10000 to 09A000.

"it is desirable to keep the "memory ceiling" -- the highest point in low memory touched by the boot loader -- as low as possible, since some newer BIOSes have begun to allocate some rather large amounts of memory, called the Extended BIOS Data Area, near the top of low memory".

when its says low memory means memory downside towards 000600 and high memory upside towards 0A0000??

Comment: See [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29#.22Low.22_memory_.28.3C_1_MiB.29) for understanding what is the low memory. Also, address `0x000000` would be the beginning of the low memory, so end of the low memory means the bigger addresses.

Comment: Thanks Shahbaz ,your comment made the picture bit more clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now first thing where is 0x100000 address is in above diagram ??

0x100000 is not on the diagram because only the first megabyte is special. Beyond that point the physical memory is contiguous at least until the 15-16MB point.

> Second thing is when its says kernel real-mode block was made relocatable to "any address between 0x10000 and end of low memory" means it was relocatable to address between 0x10000 to 000600?

Real-mode code can live anywhere below approximately 1 MB and the end is probably around there, at 0x9A000 or wherever the EBDA begins.

> when its says low memory means memory downside towards 000600 and high memory upside towards 0A0000??

You have it on the diagram, from 0xA0000 downwards, towards 0.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your kind response ,could it be perfect to say real mode code sits anywhere below 09A000 and protected mode kernel has to located to high memory(0x100000) which intillaly was placed between 090000 and 010000.

Comment: Yep, real-mode code can't be above that point. The protected-mode portion of the kernel is first loaded below 1MB and then moved to above 1MB because it's loaded using BIOS I/O functions that work in real mode only. You could, in theory, load the kernel in small portions and copy to above 1MB by switching the modes (real<->protected), but looks like it's not what's being done in practice.

Comment: One more point would like to get confirmed upon, highest address 0A0000 in the given diagram is way below the maximun 1 MB address space .

Comment: 0xA0000 to 1MB is reserved for the video memory and the ROM BIOS. You don't have normal RAM in this region.